# The + (plural noun) + has or have?

Tags: articles, subject-verb-agreement

Situation: Let's say two neighbors are talking about their neighborhood.

> Sentence: ''**The** houses here **has/have** many windows''

There is an **article**, but the *noun* that it introduces is *plural.*

Do I use **has** or **have**?

Comment: Very related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/142342/does-singular-or-plural-verb-goes-with-plural-nouns-like-trousers-glasses-scis After all, if it counts for them, then surely for your simple example. Also this one: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/96244/group-noun-singular-or-plural

Comment: @Jan The questions are different. This question almost certainly arises because the OP is not aware that *the* introduces both singular and plural noun phrases. The question you refer to, on the other hand, deals with subject-verb agreement where the noun is plural in form but can be used with a singular verb.

Comment: @JanDoggen, I dont think those links you put in correlate my question, coz they are all about compound nouns and ending with -s (measles, singular). Thx anyway.

Comment: @JimReynolds, hello sir, can you give me advice on how to be superbly accurate in grammar? I've seen you profile, I strongly believe you can gimme' some. Thx in advance Sir hehe.

Comment: Most people learn to use a language well by hearing and--especially--reading a lot of it, *not* by studying grammar directly. Read and listen to English that you can understand and that you find very interesting.

Comment: Using *the* is optional. You can use it because it indicates a *group* of houses (houses that are "here"). A specific group must be identified. But from the verb standpoint it is still a quantity of houses.

Comment: @JimReynolds, thank you sir. I always read and watch english movies, articles(national geo, discovery, and others) all these to give a boost in my english proficiency both formal and informal register. I will do what you have said, if you have another tip(s) pls. do, thx.

Comment: @user3169, dude thx. I got what you were saying. It's like when you it is already known what you are talking about, whether it is plural or singular, you add 'the'-definite article. Right? Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a definite article.   No, that article does not mark number.

The noun is plural, in both structure and meaning.   The verb form that agrees is "have".

Compare:

> The houses here have many windows.

with

> The neighborhood has many windows.

On the other hand, the indefinite article *does* mark number.   We find "a house" to be a perfectly natural and sensible noun phrase, but "a houses" is confusing and (unless "a" represents something other than the indefinite article) just plain wrong.

Comment: This answer is ok. If you can edit it to make it clearer and answer my question right off the bat(has or have) in the beginning sentence, and not about definite article. Anyway, I have learned a new thing here 'definite' and 'indefinite' coz I thought they are only in one category, which is 'article' that cannot be categorized into 2.

Comment: Ah, but you see, there's a reason for this order of presentation.  I addressed your point of confusion first and directly answered your question second, so that you can understand the answer once you've reached it.  Then, the supporting examples show how the answer works, so that you can check your new understanding.  Finally, I show how your initial point of confusion could have arisen from *over-generalizing* or *mis-applying* the answer to a different problem, so that you're less likely to do the same thing with this problem and answer.

Comment: Oh well, I'll give this a thumb's up now as the accepted answer here. Cheers.